# Binding Function to DataTrigger WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, background, converters, datatrigger

Edit: I changed a few things in my backend and my xaml, but I'm not getting either of my styles..

```
        <DataGrid 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
        Grid.Row="2"  Grid.RowSpan="5" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" 
        Tag="Text"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        x:Name="NodeDataGrid" Background="{Binding Color}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Node ID" Binding="{Binding NodeID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Temp" Binding="{Binding Temperature}">

                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>-->
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Conversion.RangeToBoolean}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                            </DataTrigger>-->
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NodeColor}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Damp" Binding="{Binding Dampness}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And in another class..

```
public class RangeToBoolean : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) < 0.5;
    }
}
```

And in my NodeColorViewModel

```
     private List<NodeColor> DetermineColor(List<NodeItem> nodes, List<NodeColor> nodeColor)
     {
        //SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        foreach (var item in nodes)
        {
            NodeColor aNode = new NodeColor();
            aNode.Color = 0;
            if (item.Temperature >= 80.0)
            {
                //aNode.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightSalmon);
                aNode.Color = 1;
            }
            else if (item.Temperature < 20.0)
            {
                //aNode.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
                aNode.Color = 2;
            }
            nodeColor.Add(aNode);
        }

        return nodeColor;
    }
}
```

And in my MainWindowViewModel

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        nodes = DetermineStatus(nodes);
        var colors = DetermineColor(nodes, nodeColor);

        var nodeColorViewModel = new List<NodeColorViewModel>();

        foreach (var item in colors)
        {
            //nodes.ForEach(c => nodeViewModel.Add(new NodeItemViewModel(c)));
            nodeColorViewModel.Add(new NodeColorViewModel(item));
        }
        NodeColor = nodeColorViewModel;
    }
```

My goal is to display a red background on only certain (higher than 80 for temperature), please let me know if you can think of the problem. Right now, only the default style is being displayed, almost like my trigger is being set off.

Comment: Is this compiling? The IValueConverter interface is incomplete based upon your snippet.  And would you  not want to declare your converter as a static resource so it can be used for binding?

Comment: Well, I have another class in my RangeToBoolean class
     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not going to happen");
        }
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well i can't see anything wrong with your binding, but i believe the bool result from your converter should be all lowercase:

In your datatrigger binding

```
Value = 'True'
```

change to lower case 'true'